# Why am I getting a SAML error with RestTemplate when I'm not using it?

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, saml, resttemplate

I am trying to consume a rest web service using RestTemplate. I am continually getting this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: classpath:\saml\samlKeystore.jks 
(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

Currently this is my RestTemplate setup (I've tried different approaches with the same result):

```
    RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<String> responseStr = rt.postForEntity(
      "https://beta.some-host.com/portal/apiv1/RequestInSight", 
      "null", 
      String.class);
    logger.info("response from propertyInsight: " + responseStr.getBody());
```

Nowhere in my app (as far as I know) do I have anything to do with SAML. No direct or transitive dependencies and no textual occurances.

I've tried running a request via cURL on the commandline and it works great.

I've also tried running this same code in different apps to see if there is some hidden config somewhere, but I still received the same error.

I do have an app that does use SAML, but I've made sure that it is not on tomcat when I run it. My tomcat seems to be the only possible connection between this two cases. Is there any tomcat config that triggers this?

In the end, my question is, are there any known issues along these lines? I am new to SAML and I must be missing something. Any hints on where I should look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ho hum, I had added the JAVA_OPTS properties needed for my app that uses SAML to my setenv.bat file. This made it hidden from my IDE. Once I removed those extra properties (which included the above path to the SAML keystore), the request was successfully made.